# I'm trying to continue an undefined offset code in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables, undefined, offset

I have code in php. The values of variables are empty but I want to continue if the variable is empty or not.

```php
$str_array = explode(",",ltrim($e4view, ", "));

if (isset($str_array[0][1][2])) {
    $f4irst = $str_array[0];
    $s4econd = $str_array[1];
    $t4hird = $str_array[2];

    echo $f4irst + $s4econd + $t4hird;
```

Comment: First, concatenation is with periods, not pluses. Plus concatenation is javascript, the plus sign in PHP is addition. Second, your array in `isset` is wrong, as it's checking for a multidimensional array instead of the individual array keys. If. you want it to continue if they're empty, the set the variables to something before your if check.

Comment: I want to add the values in integer not string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do this?

```
if (empty($str_array[0]) && empty($str_array[1] …) {
```